# What's the procedure for diluting bitumen mastic with a solvent?

Tags: sealing, materials

The can of bitumen mastic says I can add up to ten percent solvent to make the mastic easier to apply. Applicable solvents list follows. The problem is the mastic is so stiff tat if I put a stick vertically into the mastic it doesn't fall - just stands still so it's unclear how I would mix the mastic with the solvent such that it mixes uniformly and the process takes reasonable amount of time.

What's the procedure for such dilution?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the can in the sun on the next sunny day for several hours (if the ambient air temperature is warm). The sealer should be sufficiently softened to add the prescribed amount of solvent and stir with a sturdy mixing stick. (If the directions on either the solvent or the sealers label states otherwise always follow those instructions).

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. The OP was asking what kind of solvent to use to soften it.

Comment: He stated the problem was the mastic was so solid that he couldn't stir the solvent into the mastic. I suggested a solution that would enable him to do that.